# Export posts with postmeta without ID?

Tags: post-meta, mysql, export, phpmyadmin

I have some select posts on one database that I need to export and import into a different database.

Because both databases are operating independently, there is overlap with post IDs so I can't export the ID from wp_posts.

I can successfully export and import the posts, but the post meta is dropped. And, since I'm not exporting the ID, I can't export the wp_postmeta without referencing the appropriate (NEW) ID.

Any ideas on how I can transfer only some posts to a different site and keep the post_meta while ditching the ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of exporting raw SQL, instead us eth eWordPress exporter and import them that way. This way any media attachments, taxonomy terms, and post meta are all included, and all URLs are adjusted too

Comment: Won't that cause a duplicate key error? Also, WP exporter can't export based on custom field values, aka postmeta.

Comment: why would it cause a duplicate key error? The exporter doesn't use SQL, it uses XML formatted data in a file to store the exported data

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. And I guess I could open the XML file and filter by a column, delete the rest, so that I only have the posts I want. Thanks

Comment: There should also be filters and hooks so you can filter them out at runtime, I'm not sure what their names are but I know they exist ( if not there are constants you can check for during a query filters )